Issues Importing a Framework with Dependencies in Swift
I'm currently developing an umbrella framework in Swift, where one framework is dependent on another framework. Specifically, I have a framework (let's call it MainFramework) that depends on another framework (DependencyFramework).
While trying to integrate MainFramework into my test project, I encountered the following errors:

Failed to build module 'MainFramework' for importation due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug
MainFramework.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios-simulator.private.swiftinterface:7:8
No such module 'DependencyFramework'

I ensured that MainFramework is correctly set up to include DependencyFramework as a dependency.
Additional Information:

I am using Xcode version Version 15.4 (15F31d)

The deployment target for both frameworks is set to 13.5

The errors occur when I try to import MainFramework in my ViewController.swift file.


What could be causing these errors, and how can I resolve the issue of importing a framework that has dependencies on another framework? Any guidance or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated!

Xcode have buggy inplementation of swift packages support.
And XCode buggy from release to release :)
In such cases you need to clear packages cache and try to "update" and "resolve" packages.
Sometime helps resolve, sometime - update, sometime - both.
In some cases you need to do this manually several times.


thanks for being helpful, but I am not using packages. Its a very simple Xcode Project. Let me add the source link here


close Xcode & clear DerivedData folder 2) open XCode - remove your framework from relations, try to compile, add it once more - try to compile

